# How can I make a center panel expand to take up full available space in an extjs border layout?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, height, width

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky7qgvsw/):

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo:'myDiv',
        html: '<div style="background-color: blue;"></div>',
        width: 500,
        height: 280,
        border: 'layout',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Test Button',
                region: 'north'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: '<div style="background-color: red; "></div>',
                region: 'center'
            }
            ]
  });
});
```

How can I make my panel in the center expand to the available width and height without explicitly setting the width and height?

Comment: Use `layout: 'border'` and not `border: 'layout'`: http://jsfiddle.net/e0xLzf9u/

Comment: @CD This is using box instead of panel though.

Comment: with a panel: http://jsfiddle.net/e0xLzf9u/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you not define the width explicitly it will automatically take the available width but you have to define height explicitly. Here is the work around for setting available height for panel.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo:'myDiv',
        html: '<div style="background-color: blue;"></div>',
        //width: 500,
        height: (document.body || document.documentElement).scrollHeight,
        border: 'layout',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Test Button',
                region: 'north'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: '<div style="background-color: red; "></div>',
                region: 'center'
            }
            ]
  });
});
```

If you want to set height equal to any element then you can use `Ext.get('divid').getHeight()`